# Post request to MailChimp API v3 always returns unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have the following call to post a subscribe to a Mailchimp List but it returns unauthorized. I have the API key, list and username stored in the web.config which i have triple checked.

```
using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    string parameters = string.Concat("email_address=", email, "&amp;status=", "subscribed"),
           url = "https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimp.ListId"] + "/members";

    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

    wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimp.ApiKey"]);

    string result = wc.UploadString(url, parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. You're sending the email address and status as querystring parameters instead of JSON
2. Sending credentials with the WebClient in this way doesn't work properly.

Try the following:

```
var apiKey = "<api-key>";
var listId = "<your-list-id>";
var email = "<email-address-to-add>";

using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    // Data to be posted to add email address to list
    var data = new { email_address = email, status = "subscribed" };

    // Serialize to JSON using Json.Net
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    // Base URL to MailChimp API
    string apiUrl = "https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/";

    // Construct URL to API endpoint being used
    var url = string.Concat(apiUrl, "lists/", listId, "/members");

    // Set content type
    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

    // Generate authorization header
    string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(":" + apiKey));

    // Set authorization header
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);

    // Post and get JSON response
    string result = wc.UploadString(url, json);
}
```